# Python object instance missing attribute?

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

I am trying to use TKinker but also trying to understand object orientated programming. I keep getting the same error,

> File "C:/Users/User/Documents/Python Scripts/tK_Slider.py", line 28,
>   in getAngle
>       print self.scale1.get() AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'scale1'

My code,

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.scale1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=180, command=self.getAngle(1))
        self.scale1.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.scale2 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=180, command=self.getAngle(2))
        self.scale2.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.scale3 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=180, command=self.getAngle(3))
        self.scale3.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.scale4 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=180, command=self.getAngle(4))
        self.scale4.pack(side=LEFT)

    def getAngle(self, slider):
        if slider==1:
            print self.scale1.get()
        if slider==2:
            print self.scale2.get()            
        if slider==3:
            print self.scale3.get()
        if slider==4:
            print self.scale4.get()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

What am I misunderstanding here?

I thought that I had created the attribute *scale1* before I tried to query its value, so why isnt it carried over into *getAngle()*?

Comment: You call getAngle in `__init__` before `self.scale1` is set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This calls the `self.getAngle` immediately, and at that point, the `self.scale1` is not yet set.

```
self.scale1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=180, command=self.getAngle(1))
```

You need to use a lambda function for indirection:

```
self.scale1 = Scale(master, from_=0, to=180, command=lambda ev: self.getAngle(1))
```

Comment: OK I added the lamba: and now the TK window actually opens along with the following error,  TypeError: <lambda>() takes no arguments (1 given)  and I dont get any values printed to the console

Comment: add an event argument there then :D @DrBwts (see the example)

Comment: yes that's done it, I have no idea what it means but it works